# Multiple packages on Firebase cloud Function project

Tags: firebase, architecture, google-cloud-functions, package, cold-start

Is there a way to have a Firebase/Google cloud function with this kind of architecture with cli command (`firebase deploy --only functions`) ?

**Expected:**

```
.
└── functions/
    ├── function_using_axios/
    │   ├── node_modules/
    │   ├── package.json
    │   └── index.js
    └── function_using_moment/
        ├── node_modules/
        ├── package.json
        └── index.js
```

Currently, my archi look like this:

```
.
└── functions/
    ├── node_modules/
    ├── package.json
    ├── index.js
    ├── function_using_axios.js
    └── function_using_moment.js
```

The fact is, i have a lot of useless packages dependencies for some functions.
And it increase cold start time.

I know this is possible with the web UI.

**WEB UI Exemple:**

**List**
[image: List web UI]

**One package for one Function**
[image: Function with his own package]

---

**My Current Archi see on WEB UI, one Package for all functions:**
[image: One package for all functions]

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When deploying through Firebase there can only be a single `index.js` file, although `gcloud` may any different in this respect.

To ensure you only load the dependencies that each function needs, move the `require` for each dependency into the functions that need it:

```
exports.usageStats = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const module = require('your-dependency');
  // ...
});
```

Also see:

- the Firebase documentation on [organizing functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions), which shows a way to have the functions over multiple files (although you'll still need to import/export them all in index.js).